# Calculate 3-sigma for a non-gaussian distribution of GPS observations

Tags: statistical-significance, precision

I am analysing the precision of an [RTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) solution. I have a set of 2000 errors - distances from the average
[image]
and I would like to calculate the 3-sigma value, which, were it Gaussian is ~13 mm. Now, the deviations are *not at all* Gaussian, here the absolute error values
[image]
and I think that the classic calculation of sigma by sqrt(variance) is only valid for Gaussian datasets.
Is it possible to validly calculate the 3-sigma [CEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_error_probable) from this data, and if so, how?

Sorry if this is a laughable question, I last went to a maths class in 1971...

***Edit***

I have updated the XY plot, the point colours show the age, cold first, hot last;  blue -> green -> red. It is clear that at the beginning the errors were mostly negative (bottom left) and at the end they were mostly positive (top right). This is typical of GPS drift, due the changing configuration of the constellation. It would become more-or-less Gaussian after a very long time, but I need to make estimates based on thousands of points, not millions.

The number I am trying to ascertain is the chance of a point being outside a given CEP and I want this number **to be comparable** with the CEP that I would get from an infinite (close to Gaussian) set of points.

The StdDev of my data is 4.33, but 1301 out of the 2020 points = 64.4% have an error > 4.33. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the *coordinate* deviations are Gaussian (with no systematic error and comparable variances), then the absolute deviation should have a [$\chi(2)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution)--and your plot qualitatively traces it out. The more troubling question is whether quoting a CEP might be misleading, given the asymmetry of the plot. One hypothesis could be that you haven't sat long enough at the location to see the full distribution; you could be looking at a mixture of two processes with different characteristic durations and one of them is not yet fully sampled.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the prompt reply. Sorry, you're dealing with an ignoramous, I simply don't know what Chi(2) means. If I understand you correctly, I should sample much longer (say 24 hours) to get something more 'Gaussian'?

Comment: I gave you a link to the Wikipedia article in that comment--click through to learn more.  I don't know for sure whether you need to sample longer--I was only speculating based on your scatterplot.  If you were to color the points by time, that would give us a map showing *when* each point was collected.  That would reveal whether my speculations are correct.

Comment: In relation to "3 sigma" - you would need to clarify what properties you're seeking. In the univariate Gaussian case there's a particular connection between number of standard deviations from the mean and the chance of going beyond those limits, but it is different for different distributions. Are you seeking the same chance of being outside the limits, the same number of standard deviations, or do you intend something else?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have updated the question to address your remarks. I read the Chi Distribution article but it's beyond my capabilities. Sorry, I really need a 'for dummies' explanation.

Comment: @whuber I have updated the question to address your remarks

Comment: @geln_b I have updated the question to address your remarks. sorry for double post, 2 at-signs not aéllowed

Comment: Great job! The clustering by color is clear.  It demonstrates that the mean GPS location slowly wanders over time, and therefore there is *far less precision* in the mean result than one would estimate by assuming the results are independent.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for following this up, I'm very grateful for your patience with my ignorance. Indeed, GPS  wanders slowly over time, but I don't grasp what 'far less precision' implies from a statistical perspective. I have ascertained, by trial and error, that at 21mm, 5 points of the 2020 (99.752%) exceed 21mm, which gives me a 3-sigma of 21. My problem is: how do I obtain '21' from the (mean/stddev/variance/geometric mean/log(n)/wind direction/calculation-I've never-heard-of) of my (non-Gaussian (log-normal?)) dataset?